# Does Mahalanabis Distance have something to do with Min-Max normalisation?

Tags: normalization, distance-functions, z-score

Does Mahalanabis Distance have something to do with Min-Max normalisation?

I know that it has something to do with Z-score normalisation, but when I tried Mahalanabis Distance on the Min-max normalised data, it gave me the same result? Why is that? Did I miss anything? Many thanks.

Comment: Your question is vague, because you haven't explained clearly the difference between a "Z-score normalization" and "Min-max normalized data" in your application, nor what "trying Mahalanobis distance" actually means.  The duplicate shows that changing the units of measurement in the different variables shouldn't change the Mahalanobis distances themselves, though, and that seems to be the essence of your question.  If not, please feel free to edit your post.